# Problem replacing boost::bind with std::tr1::bind

Tags: c++, boost, tr1, boost-bind

I have the following code which compiles and runs fine under Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/utility.hpp>

class NoncopyableObject : public boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    NoncopyableObject(int x) : x_(x) {}
    int getValue() const {return x_;}
private:
    int x_;
};

template<class F>
class MenuItemDispatcher
{
public:
    MenuItemDispatcher(F f) : f_(f) { }

    void operator ()(NoncopyableObject& w) const
    {
        // Invoke the functor
        f_(w);
    }
private:
    typedef boost::function1<void,NoncopyableObject&> FUNC;
    FUNC f_;
};

void MenuItem()
{
    std::cout << "in MenuItem()\n";
}

template<class F>
MenuItemDispatcher<F> MakeMenuItemDispatcher(F f)
{
    return MenuItemDispatcher<F>(f);
}

int main()
{
    NoncopyableObject obj(7);
    MakeMenuItemDispatcher(boost::bind(&MenuItem))(obj);
}
```

If I change the boost::bind to std::tr1::bind in main(), I get an error:

> error C2248: `'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable'` : cannot access private member declared in class `'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable'`.
>
> This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function `'NoncopyableObject::NoncopyableObject(const NoncopyableObject &)'`

So it's trying to generate a copy constructor for NoncopyableObject. Anyone know why this might be so please? MenuItemDispatcher's call operator takes a reference to a NoncopyableObject, so I am struggling to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you break that last line into two lines?  I'm thinking one line to declare the `MakeMenuItemDispatcher` and one to call it.  Just trying to rule out some weird parsing issue with the code as it is now.

Comment: works in gcc 4.4.1, 4.5.2, fails in VS 2010 SP1. To reproduce, it's sufficient to attempt to create a boost/std function that takes `Noncopyable&` from a boost/std bind that doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a difference in how `bind` is implemented in MS Visual Studio (including 2010) and GNU gcc (I tested 4.4.1 and 4.5.2, both of which work the way you expected)

Consider the following code, given your definitions

```
auto b = boost::bind(&MenuItem);
NoncopyableObject obj(7);
b(obj);  // OK in VS and GCC
```

replacing boost::bind with std::bind (I'm using 2010, the error message appears to be the same as in your 2008)

```
auto b = std::bind(&MenuItem);
NoncopyableObject obj(7);
b(obj);  // compile error in VS 2010 SP1, OK in GCC
b(std::reference_wrapper<NoncopyableObject>(obj)); // OK in both
```

So, what happens is that MS's `bind()` makes a copy of its argument even if the argument is not going to be used, while boost's and GCC's `bind()` does not bother with that argument at all.

I was able to get your example to compile and run (on 2010) by changing the `FUNC` typedef to

```
typedef boost::function1<void, std::tr1::reference_wrapper<NoncopyableObject> > FUNC;
```

Comment: thank you so much for this. Employing reference_wrapper does the trick. I think there's one slight error in your answer: the line of code b(std::reference_wrapper<NoncopyableObject>(obj)); // OK in both should be using std::ref (or std::tr1::ref) instead I think?

Comment: @PUK You're right, using the `ref()` helper function when making the function call is a bit easier to read. It's the same as using make_pair(arg1, arg2) instead of pair<type, anothertype>(arg1, arg2);

Comment: How silly of me. Of course - it's going via a function for with template argument deduction. Thanks!